# how to add html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add following html tag in javascript

```
<i class="fa fa-building"></i>
```

In javascript file

```
title: {
            text: 'Properties'
        };
```

I have done following

```
title: {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-building"></i>Properties'
        };
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the `i` tag into the document?

Comment: and what's wrong with your code? what did you expect?

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-building"></i>Properties` is it a valid HTML?

Comment: document.write("<i class="fa fa-building"></i>");

Comment: Please include a clear description of what you are trying to achieve and what you already have. I can imagine that you are using this `text` property as the textContent of an Element and that it doesn't work the way you want, but your js makes no sense: you are only defining a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), then a code block and an other label inside that code block. All this is completely void.

Comment: I want to insert i tag into document

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` like so:

```js
var myObject = {
  title: {
    text: "Properties"
  }
};

var elem = document.querySelector("i");

myObject.title.text = elem.outerHTML + myObject.title.text;

console.log(myObject);
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-building"></i>
```

The `\"` are just escaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Get i tag by document.getElementsByTagName('i') and save it into object

```js
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
let obj = {};
obj.text =html[0];

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-building"></i>
```